# How to reach ultra low power on STM32Lxx?

Tags: current, stm32, low-power, stm32l

I'm having some problem reaching the said ultra-low power available for the STM32Lxx series. With no active register, the UC should consume around 10 uA, but I can't get it down from 1 mA. The datasheet says to first reduce the frequency, then the core voltage then enter the ultra low power mode as one can no longer program it.

The lines I use to enter the lower power mode are :

```
RCC_MSICmd(ENABLE); % Activate the Multi-speed internal clock
RCC_MSIRangeConfig(RCC_MSIRange_0); % Reduce to 32 kHz the Multi-speed internal clock
RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_MSI); % The system clock that will be used is the MSI clock.
RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div512);  % Reduce furthermore the clock frequency
RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div16); % Reduce furthermore the clock frequency
PWR_VoltageScalingConfig(PWR_CR_VOS); % Reduce the core voltage
PWR_EnterLowPowerRunMode(ENABLE); % Enter the low power run mode
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could point me the mistake I am doing.

Comment: Are you putting it in sleep or stop mode?

Comment: You need to turn off all non-essential peripherals and peripheral clocks, in addition to reducing power to the core.

Comment: If I reset the MCU completely, does't it automaticaly turn off all non-essential peripherals?

Comment: Adding to what @TimWescott said, please see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/427989/38335) answer regarding peripheral clocks.

Comment: If it's like the other ST processors it'll come out of reset with all peripherals turned off.

Comment: IIRC, those processors come out of reset with all the pins configured as floating inputs, and a floating CMOS input consumes current.  You can get a marked reduction in power consumption by configuring everything that's not actively driven high or low to have a pull-up or pull-down, as appropriate.

Comment: You have to enable the clock for the PWR module to get into low power modes. This seems strange but if worked for us.

Comment: Thank you all for your answer, I'll work on that!